# PHP: Why converting a date string to a timestamp then back to a date string doesn't work?

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

My code

```
$time = "Tuesday, 26 June 2012";
//str_replace(',','',$time);<--this also doesn't work.
$a = strptime($time, "%l, %j %F %Y");
$stmp = mktime(0,0,0,$a['tm_mon'],$a['tm_mday'],$a['tm_year'],0);
$from_stmp = date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $stmp);
echo $from_stmp; //Tuesday, 30 November 1999 00:00:00
```

Now i know there is a more elegant way, that actually works:

```
$time = "Tuesday, 26 June 2012";
$stmp = strtotime($time);
$from_stmp = date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $stmp);
echo $from_stmp;//Tuesday, 26 June 2012 00:00:00
```

But what's wrong with the first version? I'm just curious.

Comment: is `time` a typo? Should it be `$time`?

Comment: Yes, typo. Fixed it, but the output doesn't change.

Comment: Your $a = strptime(time, "%l, %j %F %Y"); returns false, So strptime is not parsing properly. Problem should be with the input date.

Comment: It still is "time", not "$time"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem #1

```
$a = strptime(time, "%l, %j %F %Y");
```

You wrote `time`; it should be `$time`.

#### Problem #2

Your format string is wrong. `strptime` doesn't use the same format strings as `date`, just with percentage signs in front; it has its own set. Your format string should look like this:

```
$a = strptime($time, "%A, %e %B %Y");
```

#### Problem #3

- `strptime` returns a number of years *since 1900*. You need to add `1900`.
- `strptime` returns a month from 0 to 11. You need to add `1`.

#### All summed up

Here's your code, fixed:

```
<?php
$time = "Tuesday, 26 June 2012";
$a = strptime($time, "%A, %e %B %Y");

$stmp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon'] + 1, $a['tm_mday'], 1900 + $a['tm_year']);
$from_stmp = date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $stmp);
echo $from_stmp;
?>
```

[Hooray, it works!](http://codepad.org/gx2F7Guz)

Comment: Thx, i saw my error with the different format string... but, your solution didn't really worked. Tuesday, 26 June 2012 != Saturday, 26 May 2012

Comment: @alex: Sorry, missed one problem :) I updated my answer. It *really* works now!

Answer (score 2):

You still have to remove the last 0 of the mktime function it should be correctly,

```
$time = "Tuesday, 26 June 2012";
$a = strptime($time, "%A, %e %B %Y");

$stmp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon'] + 1, $a['tm_mday'], 1900 + $a['tm_year']);
$from_stmp = date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $stmp);
echo $from_stmp;
```

Comment: The `0` is an optional parameter and will work just fine, read [the docs](http://ca3.php.net/mktime).

Comment: But when I tried to use with the 0 at the end I got this error, `Deprecated: mktime() [function.mktime]: The is_dst parameter is deprecated`

Comment: @itsme: You should probably just post that as a comment instead, then. I realize you don't have enough reputation, though - just for future reference. (Also, that's not an error, it's a warning.)

Answer (score 1):

The format of $time is wrong, it should be "%A, %e %B %Y".

If you var_dump $a ,

```
array(9) {
  ["tm_sec"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_min"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_hour"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_mday"]=>
  int(26)
  ["tm_mon"]=>
  int(5)
  ["tm_year"]=>
  int(112)
  ["tm_wday"]=>
  int(2)
  ["tm_yday"]=>
  int(177)
  ["unparsed"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

If you see the docs, you will find the actual values returned.

```
"tm_sec"    Seconds after the minute (0-61)
"tm_min"    Minutes after the hour (0-59)
"tm_hour"   Hour since midnight (0-23)
"tm_mday"   Day of the month (1-31)
"tm_mon"    Months since January (0-11)// increment month
"tm_year"   Years since 1900// add years from 1900
"tm_wday"   Days since Sunday (0-6)
"tm_yday"   Days since January 1 (0-365)
"unparsed"  the date part which was not recognized using the specified format
```

you find the actual values passed into your mktime, Adjust your vals passed into mktime to fix this.

```
<?
$time = "Tuesday, 26 June 2012";
$a = strptime($time, "%A, %e %B %Y");
var_dump($a);
$stmp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon'] + 1, $a['tm_mday'], 1900 + $a['tm_year']);
$from_stmp = date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $stmp);
echo $from_stmp;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well because `strptime()` is outdated !

From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) : `(PHP 5 >= 5.1.0)`

So you should use `strtotime()` ...

Comment: Well i did test it with PHP 5.4.X and i get an error ` Call to undefined function strptime() ` so i quick searched in the php docs !

Comment: It's not implemented on Windows platforms.

Comment: @minitech thanks, so now i should definitely use strtotime for cross-compatibility !

Comment: The docs say, It can only parse an output of strftime().
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php
strptime — Parse a time/date generated with strftime()